# RecyclerView duplicate ViewHolders radioButton

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an Adapter for questions and their possible answers when I select one is replicated in other parts of the Adapter and appears in other questions as if I had already selected it.

Try to pass from Main,it didn't work
setHasStableIds(true)  and getItemId():getIdPojo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv_Preguntas);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getLst());
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public List<Pojo> getLst(){
    List<Pojo>lst = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i =1;i<35;i++){
        lst.add(new Pojo(i,"Pregunta "+i+"?",0));
    }

    return lst;
}}
```

Mi Adaptador : 
I try to save it in an Object and then recover it but it doesn't work
   well.setIntReply (1);

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Adpater_VH> {

private List<Pojo> lst;

public Adapter(List<Pojo> lst) {
    this.lst = lst;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Adpater_VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv, parent, false);
    Adpater_VH viewHolder = new Adpater_VH(item);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adpater_VH holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(lst.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lst.size();
}

    @Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
}

    @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return lst.get(position).getIdRegistro();
}

public class Adpater_VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rbSi, rbNO, rbNA;

    public Adpater_VH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rv);
        rg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rg_rv);
        rbSi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbItemSi_rv);
        rbNO = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbItemNO_rv);
        rbNA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbItemNA_rv);
    }

    void bind(final Pojo pojo) {
        tv.setText(pojo.getPregunta());

        switch (pojo.getIntRespuesta()){
            case 1:
                rbSi.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                rbNO.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                rbNA.setChecked(true);
                break;

        }

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId != -1)
                    switch (checkedId) {
                        case R.id.rbItemSi_rv:
                            pojo.setIntRespuesta(1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.rbItemNO_rv:
                            pojo.setIntRespuesta(2);
                            break;
                        case R.id.rbItemNA_rv:
                            pojo.setIntRespuesta(3);
                            break;
                    }
            }
        });

    }
}}
```

vista de la APP:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QfXV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by changing
setOnCheckedChangeListener
to
setOnClickListener
The setOnCheckedChangeListener event is called even when it leaves the field of view

```
    public class Adpater_VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rbSi, rbNO, rbNA;

    public Adpater_VH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rv);
        rg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rg_rv);
        rbSi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbItemSi_rv);
        rbNO = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbItemNO_rv);
        rbNA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbItemNA_rv);
    }

    void bind(final Pojo pojo) {
        tv.setText(pojo.getPregunta());
        rg.clearCheck();
        Log.i("TAG-", pojo.getIdRegistro()+"bind: " + pojo.getIntRespuesta());
        switch (pojo.getIntRespuesta()) {
            case 1:
                rbSi.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                rbNO.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                rbNA.setChecked(true);
                break;
            default:
                rg.clearCheck();
                break;

        }

        rbSi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(rbSi.isChecked()){
                    pojo.setIntRespuesta(1);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```